# How can I get a python script to find the right Tortoise.exe if I have multiple Tortoise clients (Git, SVN) installed?

Tags: c#, python, command-line, tortoisesvn

Each tortoise client has its own executable named 'Tortoise.exe' and I'm looking for a way to differentiate them before using Python's subprocess.call or C#'s Process class

I've been using the subprocess.call() to run certain actions through TortoiseSVN.

Python:

```
call('TortoiseProc.exe /command:ignore /path:\"%s\" /closeonend:0' % url)
```

C#:

```
tortoiseSVN = new Process( );
tortoiseSVN.StartInfo.FileName = "tortoiseProc.exe";
```

This works fine, unless I have a second (or third) Tortoise client installed like TortoiseGit. My current workaround is to remove non-TortoiseSVN folders from my Windows PATH variable, but I want to find something more elegant.

Comment: If you know which one you want to use on each occasion, just use the full pathname as the first argument to `call`.

Comment: SVN_PATH = 'C:/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin'<br/>
HG_PATH = 'C:/Program Files/TortoiseHg/bin/'

url = 'url'

path = SVN_PATH
call(path + 'TortoiseProc.exe /command:ignore /path:\"%s\" /closeonend:0' % url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By way of example for Alexis comment:

```
def gen_command_string(path, url):
    cmd = path + 'TortoiseProc.exe /command:ignore /path:\"%s\" /closeonend:0' % url
    return cmd

SVN_PATH = 'C:/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin'
HG_PATH = 'C:/Program Files/TortoiseHg/bin/'

cmd = gen_command_string(SVN_PATH, 'http://google.com')
call(cmd)
```

Comment: FYI TortoiseHg does not follow the same command structure as TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit.